fat-aar plugin to support android Gradle plugin 8.5.2+
Is there any fat-aar plugin to support Android Gradle Plugin AGP 8.5.2+ ?
I know this one https://github.com/aasitnikov/fat-aar-android (latest 1.4.1) but it may support AGP up to 8.5.0 only. I got this exception in run-time when I use it with plugin 8.5.2.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.work.CoroutineWorker"
Does anyone know a solution for it?
